# SSRS report not obeying page breaks

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I inherited a report in SSRS 2005

It is a very simple report with a Page Header, Page Footer, and only a table in the body

The table has one group (by Country) I have tried to set Page Break of the group before, after  and both.  No matter which option I choose the report on the screen, through the report viewer through the browser, always shows as one continuous page instead of the desired result of Each country starting a new page.

Any ideas of what else to check which would cause this behavior?

Thanks

Edit: In Pdf Export the page breaks work

Edit: to clarify I am referring to the report viewer through the browser, not HTML export

Answer (score 3):

It works in export to PDF, but not elsewhere is because page based outputs obey page breaks.

HTML is not page based.  HTML breaks on interactive page height.

This may help: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255244.aspx

Comment: I understand what you mean technically.  But SSRS has a paging control, that seems to work on every other report.  When I compare two reports I can not find why one pages and the other does not.